# Extending Middleware for Logging and Metrics Across Various Methods, Beyond API Calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-middleware

**Note**: I'm new to c# and .net

I'm working on recording logs and metrics for APIs and specific operations. To achieve this, I'm planning to use middleware. I've implemented a basic version of middleware along with a custom attribute, and that works fine*** with API methods like 'PostUsers' in the below example code snippet.

```
namespace MyApp.Namespace1
{
    [ApiController]
    public class Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route( "users" )]
        [OperationName( "PostUsers" )] // Custom attribute to send the operation name to middleware
        public async Task PostUsers( [FromBody] UsersRequest request )
        {
            try
            {
                ...
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                ...
                // This error (ex.Message, etc.) should be available in middleware
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But when I apply the attribute and middleware to the non-controller methods like 'HandleUsers' and 'CreateStorage,' mentioned in the code snippet below, it doesn't work

```
internal class UsersProvider
{
  [OperationName( "HandleUsers" )]
  private async Task HandleUsers()
  {
  }
}


public class Storage
{
    [OperationName( "CreateStorage" )]
    private static void CreateStorage( )
    {
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve a similar pattern so that it can be applied to all types of methods?

***:  Currently, I'm passing the required details from the controller to the middleware by using HttpContext.Items. Is there any better way of doing this? My goal is to offload all the logs and metric-related logic to middleware and keep the controller/target method as clean as possible

Comment: That's already available through the OpenTelemetry middleware and instrumetnations, and the built-in ActivitySource and Activity classes. Check the [.NET OpenTelemetry Getting Started guide](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/net/getting-started/). And definitely check [.NET Aspire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/aspire-overview) which creates web apps with OpenTelemetry defaults *and* includes a dashboard that displays traces and metrics.

Comment: Your approach doesn't look like ASP.NET Core middleware. These are classes that is set up as part of configuring the app. Look at this post for an example: https://blog.elmah.io/error-logging-middleware-in-aspnetcore/. You can also create filters as attributes as you are trying to with your code. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0 for details on how to do that correctly.

Comment: How is this custom attribute being written?